# Duplicated notifications in Android

Tags: android, mobilepush-android

when I send a push in firebase console theres a problem of duplicated notifications, because etpushsdk uses gcm and my application fcm. I'm using etpushsdk 4.8.4, is there any previsition when etpushsdk will migrate to fcm to replace gcm?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: Version 5.1.3 of the Android SDK supports multiple push providers and is available for immediate consumption: http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/

A forthcoming release of the SDK will support multiple GCM providers and you should be able to configure your application to handle push notifications from both sources without incurring the duplicate notifications you're currently experiencing.

The version will be 5.1.x and is going through regression testing for release in the next few weeks.

Comment: ok, i'm waiting this version, tks

Comment: Tks, i'll verify, by now i'm not seeing any example of fcm in your documentation, is that any?

Comment: You should be able to configure your application to use FCM without interfering with the SDK's GCM implementation as of version 5.1.x.

Comment: Ok, your application uses gcm yet? I don't understand this point, because our app using firebase cloud message too, when I send pushes by sales force admin, it's ok, but when I close my application and send a push by firebase console, I receive two notifications.